# Restrict access to options-*.php pages

Tags: settings-api, user-roles

I have a custom role named `manager` with `manage_options` and `read` capabilities , i want to restrict him not to access Settings menu, you may say remove `manage_options` capability but that's not the case as i need that cap (am using Settings API which posts to options.php).

I can hide those pages by using `remove_menu_page()` but still we can access by directly typing url.

Comment: Thinking out loud could you give him some `user_meta`? if can `manage_options`  &&  user meta is `manager` direct to `header("Location: /wp-admin/")` in options.php?

Comment: How about creating a new capability? You can edit the global `$menu` so that the admin menu shows the items you require for that capability, and it's quite likely that you can hook the settings page you need the `manager` role to edit to allow that new role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty way of doing this is by adding a `.htaccess` file to the wp-admin directory, with the following content.

```
<FilesMatch "^options-(.*)\.php$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks @Fleuv ,how can we restrict only `manager` role using this..it restricts everyone.